# Which language to create web bots?

Tags: flash

I want to start writing code.
I am a beginner on Visual Basic but I think it limits my ideas so I want to start writing in a different language.
I would be happy if you could answer my question:

I want to develop little or big software that will do automated things on web. I mean, on a  button click, it will search a word etc. I know there are many of them, but I don't know one that can do these on a Flash application. I want this little software to do these on Flash, especially.

Answer (score 3):

While learning a specific language is important, it might be best to start by learning the basics of coding at a higher level than what Visual Basic can provide. I recommend looking into [python](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/). That link will walk you through not only the basics of python, but also more advanced functionality and give you insight into the world of programming and the capabilities of writing code. From here you will have an easier time switching languages because for the most part it will be a syntax switch.

Best of luck.

Comment: Python also has a wide variety of support and coming from someone who teaches a lot of beginners languages, it seems to be the easiest language for students to pick up coming from Visual Basic. While it has high functionality it keeps the syntax simple and helps you understand what is going on opposed to syntax that is often confusing/overwhelming for those coming from another language or picking up coding in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've heard a lot abour Python, many people say that it is the best for a beginner - but I am not sure about it's capabilities - maybe I am wrong. I want the language to be "long-lasting", I mean - I will look at Python, but not sure about it. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it is a lot more friendly than trying to start with java (as I did back in the day)! The important thing to remember is to keep going and to do your work honestly! Utilize all the help you have available! You'll find this website helpful and the community friendly. People will help you and don't worry about your English! Remember to upvote answers you find helpful so that others like you can find the same answers!

Comment: Yes, really - my expectations weren't negative but I couldn't imagine that kind of connected and great community :)

Comment: Trust me python is guaranteed to be as long lasting as a language like java.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but this is probably too long for a comment.

First, your English is pretty good.  People will edit your posts, and you might be able to learn from their edits, so you can improve your English.

Second, welcome to development.  Although I kind of hate VB, it really does not limit your ideas.  There are many things possible.

I prefer Java, and if I was helping a young man getting started, I would steer them towards learning that language.  One advantage of using Java is that many tools (such as eclipse) are free, and there are many experts on this site.  Ask a question and you will get good answers.

I don't know much about Flash development, but be careful not to get caught up in the "wow factor" prior to learning what you are doing.

Good luck and keep programming.

Answer (score 0):

Atakan, you and I share a lot in common. I'm about to turn 16 and I've just started trying out VB because my friends talked me into it. However, I think you've made a smart move, Flash seems to be a much better option from what I've seen. Flash has been good to be for the last couple years and I'm sure it'll be the same for you. If you have any questions with your code just ask... we can help you out!

Cheers,
Drake Swartzy

Comment: Thnak you for your answer! I am glad there are young people like you who will be my colleagues - maybe :) But it seems you got it wrong, I will not start to code on Flash, I will code on Python or Java - but my softwares will affect Flash applications. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, AS3 would not be a good tool for the kind of project you would like to do. Just the same, good luck! :)

Comment: Oh, great - I will take a look at Action Script 3.